# MUI Radio Button - Expected spacing argument Error

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

In my MUI Radio Component on the onChange event I get this weird error.

[image]

Below is my component. My feeling is that formik.setFieldValue is setting an object.

```
<Grid item xs={6} sm={6}>
    <Box display="flex" justifyContent="right" alignItems="center">
        <RadioGroup
            row
            aria-labelledby="isAddressFiscal"
            defaultValue={true}
            name="isAddressFiscal"
            onChange={(e, value) => formik.setFieldValue("isAddressFiscal", !formik.values.isAddressFiscal)}
            value={formik.values.isAddressFiscal}
        >
            <FormControlLabel value={true} control={<Radio />} label="Si" />
            <FormControlLabel value={false} control={<Radio />} label="No" />
        </RadioGroup>
    </Box>
</Grid>
```

Comment: That seems to be a grid problem instead of a radio button problem, looking at the error and considering [this Github thread](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/issues/29349). Could you please provide a demo so we can try things out?

Comment: Thanks @Asghwor , you were right, I was using a grid container two times.